# Racket: How to print structures in a filtered list?

Tags: racket

Currently, I have the following relevant code:

```
(define-struct person (work study entertainment))
(define names
  (list bill jill tim gary samantha holly ryan quin lisa jennifer jeff george beth maria simon)
 )
```

When using the command `(filter hardworker? names)` or `(filter (lambda (x) (hardworker? x)) names)` where `hardworker?` is a predicate, I receive the output `(#<person #<person> #<person>)`, indicating that three of these results followed the predicate.

Is there a way to manipulate the filtered list to somehow print the name of each variable?

I have also considered just adding a `name` field to the original struct, but I haven't been able to find any way of printing a list only by a certain value (e.g. print all of the `work` values for the current list `names`.)

This seems to be incredibly basic but I just can't find out how to do it, so I'd appreciate any help

Comment: You can add the `#:transparent` keyword after the field-name sequence. This will let you inspect the struct when your evaluate it in the interactions area.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after a while of staring at a brick wall, I figured it out. For anyone else who got stuck in this rut, you just need to take it in two steps.

Step one is the aforementioned `(filter hardworker? names)`, which will give you the list that you want to print.

Step two is to print this list with a function that recursively adds the `name` value to a new list that is returned from the function. This does, however, necessitate that you add the `name` field I considered in the last paragraph of my initial question.

This was for a homework assignment so I won't post the rest of my code for now, but if anyone is *super* stuck, just let me know I'd be happy to show you after the due date passes.